# Polymorphic treating of 2D and 3D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working with images in Python, and need to write a program that can handle both color and grayscale image. They're numpy array

Shape of Color: (512,512,3)

Shape of Grayscale:(512,512)

Now I have to loop through every channel of images, i.e. return :

```
For Color: im[:,:,0], im[:,:,1], im[:,:,2]

For Grayscale: im[:,:]
```

How to write them in the same format without any if condition? I tried im[:,:,0] for grayscale but it's out of range for the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is helpful or not, but `numpy` provides the ability to insert [new axes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing):

```
im_new = im_old[:,:,np.newaxis]
```

As I understand it, this makes it so that `im_new[i,j,k]` is the same as `im_old[i,j]` for any `k`.

(also note that `np.newaxis` is simply an alias for `None`)